# Python simple time conversion code

Tags: python, string, time

I am trying to convert time in 12-hour format to 24-hour format. I am not sure why I am getting the invalid syntax error.

```
def timeConversion(s):
    # Complete this function
    if s[-2:]=='PM':
        temp=s[:-2].split(':')
        print temp
        if temp[0]=='12':
            time= str(12)+':'+temp[1]+':'+temp[2]
        else:
            time= str(int(temp[0]+12)+':'+temp[1]+':'+temp[2]

    elif s[-2:]=='AM':
        temp=s[:-2].split(':')
        print temp
        if temp[0]=='12':
            time= '00:'+temp[1]+':'+temp[2]
        else:
            time= temp[0]+':'+temp[1]+':'+temp[2]

     return time

timeConversion("07:05:45PM")
```

Below is the error:

[image]

Comment: on which line you are getting error. Which python version are you using

Comment: I think in the second line there is an indentation

Comment: Why don't you just use `strptime` and `strftime`?

Comment: There are a lot of indentation issues. `return` is shifted one space and under `if-elif-else` block you have two levels instead of one. Either use 4 spaces everywhere or 2 (4 is more preferred).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
      time= str(int(temp[0]) + 12)+':'+temp[1]+':'+temp[2]
                           ^
                          here
```

The indentation of your `return time` line needs to be even with the `if/elif`statements.

Alternatively, you can accomplish what you are trying to do a lot easier by loading the string into a datetime object via `strptime`, then ouputting the desired format with `strftime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.strptime("07:05:45PM", "%I:%M:%S%p").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: You identified the problem correctly, but the location is wrong - closing parenthesis should be immediately after `str(int(temp[0] + 12)`.

Comment: @HughBothwell Good catch! Fixed.

Comment: I think the correct code is `str(int(temp[0]) + 12)` because we can't add a str `temp[0]` and a int `12` together.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post an answer because I can't comment, as @ILostMySpoon told you you missed a parenthesis in the casting. What I wanted to add is that usually for "illegal syntax" errors you should watch one line up with respect to the one that is throwing the error. I think that it is due to the fact the interpreter sees the "elif" line as a continuation of the precedent, and obviously it doesn't understand the syntax.